# My second carousel wont work. What did I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to get multiple carousel to work for my website but unfortunately for some reasons it just stack and does not slide when I push the arrows. I tried to copied my first carousel under my first one but only the first carousel is working. What did I do wrong? I put down my html css and Java script code down below.

```js
const prev  = document.querySelectorAll('.prev');
const next = document.querySelectorAll('.next');

const track = document.querySelectorAll('.track');

let carouselWidth = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-container').offsetWidth;

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  carouselWidth = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-container').offsetWidth;
})

let index = 0;

next.forEach(button => { 
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  index++;
  prev.classList.add('show');
  track.style.transform = `translateX(-${index * carouselWidth}px)`;
  
  if (track.offsetWidth - (index * carouselWidth) < carouselWidth) {
    next.classList.add('hide');
  }
})

prev.forEach(button => { 
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  index--;
  next.classList.remove('hide');
  if (index === 0) {
    prev.classList.remove('show');
  }
  track.style.transform = `translateX(-${index * carouselWidth}px)`;
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
.carousel-container {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-container {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .carousel-container {
    width: 85%;
  }
}
.carousel-container .carousel-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-container .track {
  display: inline-flex;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.carousel-container .card-container {
  width: 259px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 250px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.carousel-container .card-container .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.nav button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav .prev {
  left: -30px;
  display: none;
}
.nav .prev.show {
  display: block;
}
.nav .next {
  right: -30px;
}
.nav .next.hide {
  display: none;
}

.card > * {
  flex: 1;
}
.card .img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.card .info {
  flex-basis: 40px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  flex-grow: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="track">
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">1</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">2</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">3</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">4</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">5</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">6</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">7</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">8</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">9</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">9</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">9</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">9</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">9</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">9</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <button class="prev">
      <i class="material-icons">
      keyboard_arrow_left
      </i>
    </button>
    <button class="next">
      <i class="material-icons">
      keyboard_arrow_right
      </i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Second Carousel -->

<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="track">
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">1</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">2</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">3</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">4</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">5</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">6</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">7</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">8</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">9</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">9</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">9</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">9</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">9</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="img">9</div>
          <div class="info">
            Title 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <button class="prev">
      <i class="material-icons">
      keyboard_arrow_left
      </i>
    </button>
    <button class="next">
      <i class="material-icons">
      keyboard_arrow_right
      </i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So in your example you're using `document.querySelector` which is only assigning your event listeners to the first instance of each found. Hence why the first carousel buttons work, and the second instances do not because they haven't had an event listener attached. You'll need to make those instances unique or perhaps do like `querySelectorAll` and loop through the found instances to assign the event listener to each. Except then you'll still need to separate the instances that they're interacting with as well unless the buttons should control both the same.

Comment: `document.querySelector()` returns only one element. You need to use `document.querySelectorAll()` and loop on elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.querySelector()` only selects the first match it encounters, so your `prev` and `next` variables are only assigned to the buttons in your first carousel.

To match all instances, use `.querySelectorAll()` and then loop through the results when adding your `eventListener`, like so:

```
const next = document.querySelectorAll('.next');

next.forEach(button => { 
  button.addEventListener('click', () => ...your code...) 
})
```

Comment: Hey thank you for taking the time to help me first off. And for some reason when I added this it still didnt work. Instead now neither carousels is working now.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read your code more closely before responding.  You're reusing a lot of code between the two carousels, which is going to cause some issues: for instance, you only have one `index` value which means both carousels are using the same index.  Unless you want both carousels to move at the same time anytime you click a button, they should really be separated more clearly.  You could do this by naming them uniquely in the HTML, or you could move your `eventListener` callback to 
 separate function(s) that are called for both carousels.

Comment: @HennyC I don't know if this will help at all, but I've created a CodePen demonstrating one way to make multiple carousels work.  Only the JavaScript has been changed: I've moved most of your JS code into a factory function that creates a Carousel object and then apply this factory function to all carousels on the page.  So now, each carousel's information, like its track, index, etc., is stored inside its own object.  This isn't necessarily the "best" way to do this, but if fixes the issue of your carousels interfering with each other.  https://codepen.io/jwern/pen/VwpoJMQ

Comment: Thank you so much bro! I was trying to figure out what I was doing wrong all yesterday. Now I am kind of understanding what I was doing wrong thanks to your help! So again thank you.